# Getting error while running Raspberry Pi Camera

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, camera, raspicam

I am using a Raspberry Pi along with the camera module to build a spy camera standalone device, (just for learning). I ran [this code](https://github.com/KanoComputing/spy-camera/blob/master/run.py) on my Raspberry Pi which gave the following error:

```
initialising, please wait...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 314, in 'calling callback function'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 129, in _control_callback
    "Received unexpected camera control callback event, 0x%08x" % buf[0].cmd)
picamera.exc.PiCameraRuntimeError: Received unexpected camera control callback event, 0x4f525245
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 216, in <module>
    main()
  File "run.py", line 74, in main
    MotionDetector(send_email, username, password, smtp_server_url, user_email, trigger_level)
  File "run.py", line 108, in __init__
    for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream, format='jpeg'):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1853, in capture_continuous
    'Timed out waiting for capture to end')
picamera.exc.PiCameraRuntimeError: Timed out waiting for capture to end
```

Also when I run `raspistill -o abc.jpeg` I get the following error:

```
mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board
```

I checked the connection. When I run raspistill the LED lights up (and stays lit up) but it doesn't take a picture.

So far I have tried the following:

- Adding `blacklist spi-bcm2708` and `blacklist i2c-bcm2708` to my `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf`
- switching the pin used for 1-Wire to pin 18 in `/boot/cmdline.txt:`

  `dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait bcm2708.w1_gpio_pin=18`
- Enabling and disabling the camera in `raspi-config`
- Running `sudo apt-get install rpi-update` and `sudo rpi-update`
- Tried uninstalling and reinstalling Raspbian

But none of this has worked so far. What could be possibly wrong?

Comment: Have you tried what the error message says and "checked the connectione?"

Comment: Yes, I did check the connection. When I run `raspistill` the LED lights up (and stays lit up) but it doesn't take a picture.

Comment: Check that the "SUNNY" labelled chip on the camera board is properly seated in its connector (carefully unplug and reseat it if necessary - obviously don't do this while the camera has power). If you still get the same error, you've most likely got a dead camera. They are quite sensitive components, and relatively easy to kill if accidentally touched to conductive things (or the 5V pins on the Pi!)